# Unable to show Drawer and Tab Bar together using react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using react-native with react-native-router-flux and I want to use both Drawer sidemenu and also tabbar. But it only shows the one I put on top. My code is below. If I put **Drawer** first then it only shows Drawer.

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native'; 
import { Router, Scene, Stack, Tabs, Drawer } from 'react-native-router-flux'; 
import ScarletScreen from './component/ScarletScreen'; 
import ProfileScreen from './component/ProfileScreen'; 
import WhiteScreen from './component/WhiteScreen'; 
import BlackScreen from './component/BlackScreen'; 
import SideMenu from './component/SideMenu';

const TabIcon = ({ selected, title }) => {   return (
    <Text style={{color: selected ? 'red' :'black'}}>{title}</Text>   ); }

export default class App extends React.Component {   render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>   
            {/* Drawer and it's scenes */}      
            <Drawer key="drawer" drawerImage={require('./img/hamburger.png')} contentComponent={SideMenu}>
              <Scene key="main">
                  <Scene
                      key="scarlet"
                      component={ScarletScreen}
                      title="Scarlet Screen"
                      initial
                  />
                  <Scene
                      key="profile"
                      component={ProfileScreen}
                      title="Profile"
                  />
                  <Scene
                    key="white"
                    component={WhiteScreen}
                    title="White Screen"
                  />
                  <Scene
                    key="black"
                    component={BlackScreen}
                    title="Black Screen"                    
                  />                                  
              </Scene>
            </Drawer> 
            {/* Tab and it's scenes */}
            <Tabs
              key="tabbar"
              tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}
            >
              {/* Tab and it's scenes */}
              <Scene key="osu" title="OSU" icon={TabIcon}>
                <Scene
                  key="scarlet"
                  component={ScarletScreen}
                  title="Scarlet Screen"
                />
                <Scene
                  key="white"
                  component={WhiteScreen}
                  title="White Screen"
                />
              </Scene>

              {/* Tab and it's scenes */}
              <Scene key="um" title="UM" icon={TabIcon}>
                <Scene
                  key="white"
                  component={WhiteScreen}
                  title="White"
                />
                <Scene
                  key="black"
                  component={BlackScreen}
                  title="Black"
                />
              </Scene>
            </Tabs>                                 
          </Scene>
      </Router>     
    );   } }
```

[image]
[image]

If I put tabbar first, then it shows the tabbar only and the hamburger menu icon is gone.

```
  {/* Tab and it's scenes */}
  <Tabs
    key="tabbar"
    tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}
  >
    {/* Tab and it's scenes */}
    <Scene key="osu" title="OSU" icon={TabIcon}>
      <Scene
        key="scarlet"
        component={ScarletScreen}
        title="Scarlet Screen"
      />
      <Scene
        key="white"
        component={WhiteScreen}
        title="White Screen"
      />
    </Scene>

    {/* Tab and it's scenes */}
    <Scene key="um" title="UM" icon={TabIcon}>
      <Scene
        key="white"
        component={WhiteScreen}
        title="White"
      />
      <Scene
        key="black"
        component={BlackScreen}
        title="Black"
      />
    </Scene>
  </Tabs>  
  {/* Drawer and it's scenes */}      
  <Drawer key="drawer" drawerImage={require('./img/hamburger.png')} contentComponent={SideMenu}>
    <Scene key="main">
        <Scene
            key="scarlet"
            component={ScarletScreen}
            title="Scarlet Screen"
            initial
        />
        <Scene
            key="profile"
            component={ProfileScreen}
            title="Profile"
        />
        <Scene
          key="white"
          component={WhiteScreen}
          title="White Screen"
        />
        <Scene
          key="black"
          component={BlackScreen}
          title="Black Screen"                    
        />                                  
    </Scene>
  </Drawer>
```

[image]

I use [create-react-native-app](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) to create my react-native app